# Migrating Email Messages from one salesforce org to another salesforce org

Tags: migration, emailmessage

I exported EmailMessages and EmailMessageRelation from Source org and Imported it to Target Org.

**Lead Layout (Source Org) -** I can see 2 related list 
1. Activity History(when clicked opens outbound message) 
2. HTML Email Status(when clicked opens task). 
I can see the email record in both related list(outbound message and task).

**Lead Layout (Target Org) -** I can see email record in only Activity History and not HTML Email Status. I have the record id for both outbound message and task and am able to open it by putting id in url.

Is this a known Issue? If yes can anyone provide me with the knowledge article/solution regarding the same.